# Java map Set to another Set (Using Model Mapper or Any other way)

Tags: java, set, hashset, modelmapper

In the project currently I'm working on, has a Project class,

```
public class project {
  private Integer projectId;
  private String projectName;
  //getters & Setters
}
```

This project is using as a **Set** in User class

```
public class User {
  private Integer userId;
  private Set<Project> projects;
  //getters & Setters
}
```

I need to map this User class to UserDto. UserDto is like below.

```
public class UserDto {
  private Integer userId;
  private Set<ProjectDto> projectDtos;
  //getters & Setters
}
```

The ProjectDto is also same as Project class.

```
public class projectDto {
  private Integer projectId;
  private String projectName;
  //getters & Setters
}
```

To map User and UseDto, I tried below code. But it's giving an error.

```
private UserDto map(User user) {
  UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
  userDto.setUserId(user.getUserId());
  Set<ProjectDto> projectDto= new HashSet<>();
  Type setType = new TypeToken<HashSet<ProjectDto>>(){}.getType();
  projectDto = modelMapper.map(user.getProjects(), setType);
  userDto.setProjectDto(projectDto);
  return userDto;
}
```

Following error is returned:

> failed to convert org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet to
> java.util.Set

It'd be great if you could support me for this. Answers without using ModelMapper are also welcome.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: First you have to set ProjectDTO object from user.getProject()  e.g. new ProjectDTO(project.get...); add it setOfProjectDto and then add to userDto.setProjectDto(setOfProjectDto). let me know if you required full code.

Comment: what is in the logic inside "setProjectDto" method?

Comment: @SanuraHettiarachchi There's no any logic. Just setting the object.

Comment: Type setType = new TypeToken<Set<ProjectDto>>(){}.getType();
can you try using a set instead of HashSet?

Comment: @HiteshKumar Ok. It's same as the answer provided by Qiu Zhou right? It worked! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @SanuraHettiarachchi Already tried that. It's giving the same error.

Comment: great, Thank you @koko

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first add a constructor to ProjectDto class:

```
public class ProjectDto {

  private Integer projectId;
  private String projectName;

   public ProjectDto(Integer projectId, String projectName) {
      this.projectId = projectId;
      this.projectName = projectName;
   }
   //getters & Setters
}
```

then with java 8 stream API, it can be done like this:

```
private UserDto map(User user) {
    UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
    userDto.setUserId(user.getUserId());
    userDto.setProjects(user.getProjects().stream()
            .map(project -> new ProjectDto(project.getProjectId(), project.getProjectName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    return userDto;
}
```